# ¿Como ajustar ventanas al .fxml que se esta abriendo?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Bueno lo que quiero realizar es que al darle clic en un cierto botón este me mande a otra ventana, bueno eso ya lo realiza, lo que pasa es que quiero que esa ventana mida mas que la ventana principal (re dimensionar su tamaño).

Método que me manda a la pantalla que quiero re dimensionar

```
public void Ayuda() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../Vista/Login/Ayuda.fxml"));
          Pane cmdPane = (Pane) fxmlLoader.load();
          cmdPane.maxHeight(1000);
          cmdPane.maxWidth(900);
          try {
              content.getChildren().clear();
              content.getChildren().add(cmdPane);
              } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              }
```

Clase inicial que carga el login

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../Vista/Login/Login.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            primaryStage.setMinHeight(502);
            primaryStage.setMinWidth(610);
            primaryStage.setMaxWidth(610);        
            primaryStage.setMaxHeight(502);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Asi me aparece la pantalla que deberia hacerse mas grande
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Nota: Debería haber espacio entre los botones finales y el borde de la ventana***

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente, abre tu fxml con scene builder y modifica las dimensiones del anchor pane que deseas. Luego en el metodo que abre la ventana deberias implementar un  codigo asi.

El controller deberias cambiarlo por tu controller, el que maneja tu archivo fxml, en mi caso es FXMLControllerPantallaPrincipal.

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(FXMLControllerPantallaPrincipal.class.getResource("FXMLLogin.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a setear el tamaño mínimo de tu nueva ventana.

```
 cmdPane.minHeight(X);
 cmdPane.minWidth(Y);
```